# Dual-boot Ubuntu / Windows 10 on SSD + HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, windows-10

*Hi there, newbie here !*

I'm going to have a 256 GB SSD very soon (mSATA 850 EVO) to accompany my 1 TB HDD (7.2k TPM) on a laptop, and I want to take advantage of this to format the HDD (with obvious backup of the data I want to keep).

This is the first time I will have Linux on my own PC (mostly for studies in computer science), the first time I try Windows 10, that I have a SSD, and my first dual boot !

So I took a long time reading tutorials, documentation and such, and came up with something like this to set all my things up :

---

### SSD :

- Windows OS and most (probably all) programs and games : NTFS (210 GB)
- Ubuntu

  - `/` : ext4 (20 GB)
  - `/usr` : ext4 (15 GB)
  - `/boot/efi` : ext4 (250 MB)

### HDD :

- Data (music, vids, photos, movies, documents) : NTFS (700 GB)
- AltPrograms (if SSD runs out of space) : NTFS (100 GB)
- Ubuntu

  - `swap` : none (8 GB)
  - `/var` : ext4 (3 GB)
  - `/tmp` : ext4 (8 GB)
  - `/home` : ext4 (50 GB)

---

Basically, what I want to do here is drastically increase my system's performance and take care of my SSD for maximum longevity (limit the write cycles). That is why I put `swap`, `/var`, `/tmp`, and `/home` on the HDD.

I also would like to hear your advice on having the `swap` in RAM (mine is 8GB big) and `/home` having symbolic links for Pictures, Documents, Videos, Music leading to the Data (NTFS) partition, because some people say it's nice, some that it's bad and should instead use a `/media/transferthingies` (NTFS) partition to exchange files between the two OS.

Oh and about the `/boot/efi` partition, do I really need it ?

---

About the installation process, I believe it is something like :

1. Reserve space on SSD and HDD with Ubuntu CD for NTFS and ext4 partitions
2. Install Windows 10 with Windows CD
3. Install Ubuntu with Ubuntu CD
4. Make symbolic links in `/home` to my Data (NTFS) partition

---

Anything I missed ? I hope I didn't, this post is already long...

Thanks for at least reading through this, and thanks in advance for those who will lend a hand :)

Comment: How did this end up working for you? I'm getting a new machine in the new year and will be doing a similar set up.

Answer (score 4):

Well, here's how I would do it:

1. Create and format all partitions to be used by *Windows only*.
2. Install Windows 10 in either BIOS or EFI mode.
3. Get a few cups of coffee while this installs.
4. Install Ubuntu from the CD/DVD, and select to use your own partitioning (Make sure to boot from the Ubuntu DVD using the same mode you installed Windows in - BIOS or EFI).
5. Create the Ubuntu partitions.
6. Let it install Ubuntu.
7. Get a cup of coffee while it installs.
8. Check to see that it boots to the GRUB2 boot manager.
9. Boot into each OS and make sure both have Identical network configurations.  e.g. IP address, hostname, etc.  You might want to add an identifier to the end of the hostname to distinguish which OS you're in, like this:  MyAwesomePC-Win10 and MyAwesomePC-Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially about the network configs.

Well seeing the amount of answers I got, I'll just try it now.

Comment: I am looking for the similar setup with SSD and HDD. Can you share the procedure if you have managed to do it?

Comment: Please ask an independent question and I'll give you an answer to that.  Once you ask that question you can paste the link to it here in the comments.

Comment: My setup is identical. But I got stuck at step #4. Where it says "This computer currently has no detected operating systems..." and then at partitioning page I found my whole SSD (/sda) as a free space (I'm sure I have win10 there).

Comment: Did you install Windows 10 in EFI mode?

Comment: Because is Windows 10 is in EFI, and Ubuntu is in BIOS \*shudders at the thought\*

Comment: 1,I hava a SSD  with windows 10 installed; HDD unpartition;
2,Make uefi Boot USB under win10 with ubuntu 16.04 in it;
3,Install ubuntu on HDD(/dev/sda);
4,Failed to boot into HDD (ubuntu);
5,Partion HDD in windows to NTFS,  reinstall ubuntu;
6,select install ubuntu alongside windows 10;
7,No GRUB screen, boot directly into windows;
8,Reboot into BIOS ,select HDD the first boot device, don't work,automatically  come back to the BIOS select screen.
lenovo T420, uefi items in BIOS; In windows, I checked C:\Windows\Panther\Setupact.log, there is "detected boot environment:BIOS",not "UEFI".

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution. I think you shouldn't divide your SSD drive to a lot of partitions like that. It will make your SSD slower.
I think you have to choose 1 OS to install all of that OS to SSD drive. Because you just have 256GB SSD so I think Linux OS is a good choose. 
SSD:

```
/          20GB
/usr       80->100GB
/another....(don't need /boot partition as little partitions as possible)
```

At this time, Linux supported a lot of program. If you are woking in computer science, I thought you had to install a lot of very heavy program like: 
Visual, CSS, Quartus,.v..v. So 80->100GB is enough for install all of that program, and maybe you play game too.
Your HHD you will install all of Windows OS, and store films, documents,..v..v
That is just my opinion. Good luck bro